# How can I recover my photos from the Vault app when the phone is lost?

Tags: samsung

I'm a Samsung Galaxy Grand user. I loaded photos to the Vault app without any problems. However, I  lost my phone.

What can I do to recover my photos?

Comment: Buy a new phone and keep backups in future.

Comment: @sachin berde was it a free or a premium (paid app) that you installed.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you can do.  Your phone is gone, and without a backup, you've unfortunately lost all your data.

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost thing of a Backup is that it's just a copy of your data which is stored separately away from your device on some storage(pen drive, laptop , Pc etc.)

In case you loose the phone, update your software, format the data by mistake or wanted(for updating etc.)  then you connect the device to a system, laptop and re-store the data back which you had stored earlier.

Depending on the device manufacturer you have various backup options available free of cost. In this case yours Is Samsung so you will be having Samsung Kies that helps you in doing the above tasks with ease and with .

There's a very bleak chance of you  getting back the valuable pictures that you have lost(1 out of 100).What I can suggest you is to get in contact with vault support team (email the support team given in the bottom of the app) and explain your situation to them if they possibly have a copy then they might give you.

In the future never forget to take backup and keep updating it (the old backup may not have much data compared to the present day backup).Most of us ignore it despite the fact that software/hardware is prone to glitches and the backup comes free of cost(in case you have huge data you backup like in 15 GB and above you may be charged for the storage in case of Drive,whereas Samsung Kies depends only on your System Limits)